# How to get thumb images as individual slide images?

Tags: shopify

I am using Brooklyn Shopify theme in mobile the main featured image is in single slide and all the thumbs in one slide, butnow I want each thumb images as single slideshow images just like featured image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using some CSS tricks and duplicating fetching of images.

In `Product.liquid` file duplicate the code images fetched as you said you are using Brooklyn theme I will help you with the same.

Find for this code

```
<div class="grid product-single">
    <div class="grid__item large--seven-twelfths medium--seven-twelfths text-center">
      <div class="product-single__photos">
        {% assign featured_image = current_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}

        {% comment %}
          Display current variant image, or default first
        {% endcomment %}
        <div class="feature_image top_feature_image">
         <div class="product-single__photo-wrapper">
          <img class="product-single__photo" id="ProductPhotoImg" src="{{ featured_image | img_url: 'grande' }}" {% if settings.product_zoom_enable %}data-mfp-src="{{ featured_image | img_url: 'grande' }}"{% endif %} alt="{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}" data-image-id="{{ featured_image.id }}">
        </div>
        </div>

        {% comment %}
          Display rest of product images, not repeating the featured one
        {% endcomment %}
         <div class="thumb_images">
           {% for image in product.images | limit:4 %}
            <div class="product-single__photo-wrapper">
              <img class="product-single__photo" src="{{ image.src | img_url: 'grande' }}" {% if settings.product_zoom_enable %}data-mfp-src="{{ image.src | img_url: '1024x1024' }}"{% endif %} alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}" data-image-id="{{ image.id }}">
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

then Replace with

```
<div class="grid product-single">
    <div class="grid__item large--seven-twelfths medium--seven-twelfths text-center">
      <div class="product-single__photos">
        {% assign featured_image = current_variant.featured_image | default: product.featured_image %}

        {% comment %}
          Display current variant image, or default first
        {% endcomment %}
        <div class="feature_image top_feature_image">
         <div class="product-single__photo-wrapper">
          <img class="product-single__photo" id="ProductPhotoImg" src="{{ featured_image | img_url: 'grande' }}" {% if settings.product_zoom_enable %}data-mfp-src="{{ featured_image | img_url: 'grande' }}"{% endif %} alt="{{ featured_image.alt | escape }}" data-image-id="{{ featured_image.id }}">
        </div>
        </div>

        {% comment %}
          Display rest of product images, not repeating the featured one
        {% endcomment %}

        {% for image in product.images | limit:3 %}
            <div class="product-single__photo-wrapper desk">
              <img class="product-single__photo" src="{{ image.src | img_url: 'grande' }}" {% if settings.product_zoom_enable %}data-mfp-src="{{ image.src | img_url: '1024x1024' }}"{% endif %} alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}" data-image-id="{{ image.id }}">
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
         <div class="thumb_images">
           {% for image in product.images | limit:4 %}
            <div class="product-single__photo-wrapper">
              <img class="product-single__photo" src="{{ image.src | img_url: 'grande' }}" {% if settings.product_zoom_enable %}data-mfp-src="{{ image.src | img_url: '1024x1024' }}"{% endif %} alt="{{ image.alt | escape }}" data-image-id="{{ image.id }}">
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Now open `theme.scss.liquid` file and for desktop add this

```
.desk {
  display: none;
}
```

`.desk` is the custom class taken by me

and in mobile style ie 767px add this.

```
.product-single__photo-wrapper.desk {
  display: block;
}
  .thumb_images {
  display: none !important;
}
  .slick-dots > li:last-child, .slick-dots > li:nth-last-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

This will solve your requirement.